# Redirect users by referrer from all subdomains of one domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to figure it out is this is possible.

I have two files: main1.html and main2.html

By default I send users to main1.html but specific users that comes form specific websites (I check referres of these users) are send to main2.html.

Unfortunately one of these specific websites are sending users from hundreds different subdomains as referrer.

In normal situation I use .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*xxx.org.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*yyy.org.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*zzz.com.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*aaa.net.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your_site/different_page/
```

or PHP

```
$refs = array("http://referer1.com","http://referer2.com");
  if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$refs)) {
      header("location: http://redirected_here.com");
  }
```

but adding manual these subdomains is impossible.

I there a way to redirect users from ALL subdomains without manual adding these subdomains to .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the referrer URL is subdomain of one the defined domains by extracting the "host" bit from the referrer URL and comparing it from the left:

```
// Define the domain list. Redirect if user is from one of these domains
$domains = Array('example.com', 'another.com');

// Extract the 'host' component of the referrer URL
$url_info = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

if (isset($url_info['host'])) {
    foreach($domains as $domain) {
        // Match the referrer from the left side to check if referrer is subdomain 
        if (substr($url_info['host'], -strlen($domain)) == $domain) {
            header("location: http://redirected_here.com");
        }
    }
}
```